# Proguard generating notes for all INSTANCE fields with kotlin-reflect

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, proguard, kotlin-reflect

I've added the kotlin-reflect library to my Android project, and now Proguard is generating hundreds of lines of notes, listing all classes that have a field named `INSTANCE`, which of course includes every single Kotlin `object`.

Here's just a short part of the Proguard output:

```
Note: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$objectInstance$2 accesses a declared field 'INSTANCE' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'co.zsmb.example.proguardkttest.MySingleton { co.zsmb.example.proguardkttest.MySingleton INSTANCE; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'kotlin.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE { kotlin.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE INSTANCE; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'kotlin.Unit { kotlin.Unit INSTANCE; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'kotlin._Assertions { kotlin._Assertions INSTANCE; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'kotlin.collections.EmptyIterator { kotlin.collections.EmptyIterator INSTANCE; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'kotlin.collections.EmptyList { kotlin.collections.EmptyList INSTANCE; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'kotlin.collections.EmptyMap { kotlin.collections.EmptyMap INSTANCE; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'kotlin.collections.EmptySet { kotlin.collections.EmptySet INSTANCE; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'kotlin.comparisons.NaturalOrderComparator { kotlin.comparisons.NaturalOrderComparator INSTANCE; }'
```

As you can see, it includes both my own `MySingleton` class, as well as many classes from the Kotlin standard library, and it finds these fields in any other libraries too, if they're present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of the error tells us what's wrong here, it found that whatever `kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$objectInstance$2` is, it's accessing a field named `INSTANCE` via reflection. Proguard can't tell which class it is that this code accesses the `INSTANCE` field of, so it warns us about every single class that has this field, just in case.

If we look at the [source of `KClassImpl`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/a58acdd537aadd9706927c11924897e506105a83/core/reflection.jvm/src/kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/KClassImpl.kt), we'll find the [culprit](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/a58acdd537aadd9706927c11924897e506105a83/core/reflection.jvm/src/kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/KClassImpl.kt#L112) quickly: it contains a property called `objectInstance`, which calls the [`Class#getDeclaredField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)) method in some cases, passing in a constant with the value `"INSTANCE"` as the parameter. This is what Proguard is detecting.

So, unless you have a singleton class, and you're accessing its instance via its `KClass`, like so:

```
val instance = MySingleton::class.objectInstance
```

You can ignore the Proguard note with the following rule added to your `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-dontnote kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$objectInstance**
```

You can also end it precisely with `objectInstance$2`, but an implementation change in the library could change that positional number in the future. This way, you're ignoring all notes that would appear about the `objectInstance` property and its implementation.